# Apache2 Proxy Pass

Tags: apache, docker

I've been playing around with trying to stand up a server that simply proxies requests to it to a different website (https://github.com) in this simple example and I just haven't been able to get it to work.

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi curl

RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN service apache2 restart
```

That I'm running with `docker run -it -p 80:80 --name apache proxy-test /bin/bash` after building it

Once in the container, I created this file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.docker.biz.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test-apache.biz
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass "/github" "https://github.com"
ProxyPassReverse "/github" "https://github.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then ran:

```
a2ensite site1.docker.biz.conf
service apache2 reload
```

I want to be able to go to `http://localhost:80/github` and see `https://github.com` but I get a `The requested URL /github was not found on this server.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `Dockerfile` doesn't have a `CMD` line, so a container based on the image isn't going to do anything (it'll have the `ubuntu` default of just running a shell, which isn't so useful).  `RUN service ... restart` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: My goal was to create a barebones container that I could hack on. Obviously I'm going to enhance the Dockerfile to do more things when I have another service I want to attach to another port but for now I simply posted a barebones example to see where I was going wrong